# Почему разные версии Андроид по разному реагируют на одинаковые методы

Tags: android, java

При попытке потестировать свою программу на разных версиях Андроид, обнаружил что она неустойчиво работает, и чем старее версия андроид, тем стабильнее.
Например

```
try { urlConnection.connect(); } catch (IOException e) { e.printStackTrace(); Log.d(LOG_TAG, "e= "+e.toString());}
```

На этой строке, программа споткнулась и закрылась в версии 4.0.3
а на этой:

```
   reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
```

в версии 4.2.2

а в версии 2.3.7 все работает. 
Тестировал на живых устройствах, без эмуляторов.

Как понять почему и что может не нравится системам?

Comment: Очевидно глянуть лог. Прикрепите лог и сразу станет ясно.

Comment: например работа с сетью в UI потоке

Comment: а если это связано с UI потоком, как это исправить? Попробовал разные варианты, но результат тот же: на старой версии 2.3.7 все работает, а на новых нет.

Comment: 03-19 23:24:16.762    3843-3843/com.ru.MyZXing2 D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
03-19 23:24:16.762    3843-3843/com.ru.MyZXing2 W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x409f61f8)
03-19 23:24:16.842    3843-3843/com.ru.MyZXing2 E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL 03-19 23:29:58.712    1976-1976/com.google.process.gapps D/GTalkService/c﹕ [HeartbeatAlarm] sent heartbeat to server
03-19 23:30:13.052    3674-3678/com.cleanmaster.mguard:service D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed 333K, 8% free 7088K/7687K, paused 2ms+3ms

Comment: вставьте сюда страктрейс ошибки. То что вы вставили в предыдущий комментарий - не то что нужно.    
Начиная с версии 3.0 работа с сетью запрещена в главном потоке. ЕЕ надо выносить во второстепенные. Гугл знает как.

Comment: Да, проблема была в этом. Вынес в отдельный поток и заработало.
Теперь проблема в другом
http://hashcode.ru/questions/409923/java-как-отловить-окончание-процесса-в-отдельном-потоке

Comment: Если используете Thread то надо thread.join(); и вы попросту будете ждать завершение своего потока

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как известно, от уровня к уровню( API Level ) система становится безопаснее для конечного пользователя, богаче набором доступных тулз для разработчика. Порой нововведения идут вразрез с уже, вроде бы, закрепленными стандартами. Именно поэтому всего тут не предугадаешь. Именно поэтому не бойтесь смотреть лог и делайте это почаще.

Как я уже говорил кому-то здесь, не пренебрегайте чтением новых API стандартов. Хотя бы поверхностно. Это правда важно!

P.S

Не нужно сюда кидать какие-либо выдержки из лога. Обычно суть ошибки заключается в 1-2 строчках оттуда, все же остальное - это стектрейс, который может быть интересен непосредственно для того, кто разрабатывал логику приложения.